SIGTERM with named Docker volumes
I am facing a weird issue while developing an nginx container. In this scenario, I need to connect between 2 services, namely nginx and goaccess. If I do bind mount, they work great, but if I replace it with a named volume, an issue happens that I don't understand.
Working
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx

  goaccess:
    image: allinurl/goaccess:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-logs:/srv/logs:ro
    command: >
      --log-format=COMBINED
      --log-file=/srv/logs/access.log
      --real-time-html
    ports:
      - "7890:7890"
    depends_on:
      - nginx

Compose logs:
Attaching to goaccess-1, nginx-1
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx-1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx-1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
goaccess-1  |  [SETTING UP STORAGE /srv/logs/access.log] {0} @ {0/s}
WebSocket server ready to accept new client connections  

This works perfectly. goaccess runs normally and everything is great. Nginx output are printed to the mount files and are not displayed in the compose logs. However, I don't really want an explicit mount on the host system.
Not Working
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx

  goaccess:
    image: allinurl/goaccess:latest
    volumes:
      - nginx-logs:/srv/logs:ro
    command: >
      --log-format=COMBINED
      --log-file=/srv/logs/access.log
      --real-time-html
    ports:
      - "7890:7890"
    depends_on:
      - nginx

volumes:
  nginx-logs:

Compose logs:
Attaching to goaccess-1, nginx-1
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx-1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx-1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx-1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.27.0
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
nginx-1     | 2024/10/16 10:51:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 36

Apparent in this version's logs is that goaccess service doesn't output anything unlike the previous one.
I explicitly inspected the logs of goaccess with docker logs right then and see this:
 [PARSING /srv/logs/access.log] {0} @ {0/s}
SIGTERM caught!
Closing GoAccess...
Cleaning up resources...

The SIGTERM caught! is probably why it stopped, and I don't know why this may happen when switching between mounting to volume.
If I visit localhost, the nginx logs are printed as part of docker compose logs. This didn't happen in the bind mount, which is why I think it may be related to nginx.

Any ideas why the behavior is different between the named volume version and the bind mount version?
I tried changing bind mounts to named volumes, expected it to work seamlessly, but it did not.
